# Проект собирается со студии, но при установке apk файла на телефон не ставится(android)

Tags: java, android

При сборке проекта на эмулятор, все работает, но при установке apk файла через файловый менеджер возникает ошибка о том, что приложение не получилось установить.

Вроде как раньше подобные проблемы решались отключение instant run, но в новой версии студии он заменен на apply Chnges(у меня все галочки убраны). Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.omen.serverforcofe" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: А что пишет студия при ошибке установки?

Comment: режим разработчика включен? и режим USB - отладки?

Comment: а у вас на устройстве есть поддержка nfc?

Comment: многое зависит от прошивки и настроек аппарата, если ставить по шнурку из студии, то там должна быть ошибка поиск, по которой дает точное описание выставления настроек в телефоне, потом его перезагрузку, после чего все ставится

Answer (score 0):

Возможно был не до конца удален старый apk на телефоне.
Попробуй удалить его через ADB `adb uninstall <package_name>`

Comment: Пробовал ставить на чистый телефон и все равно не устанавливается